# java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved when using drawString

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public void drawCities(ArrayList<City> cities, Graphics page)
{
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        int dim[]=cities.get(i).getLocation();
        String name= cities.get(i).getName();
        int x= dim[0]*2;
        int y=dim[1]*2;
        page.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);
        page.drawString(name, x, y);
    }
}
```

In Eclipse, when trying to compile this code I get an error, stating

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:
Unresolved compilation problem: The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved.
It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

at TravelPanel.<init>(TravelPanel.java:26)
at TravelGUI.<init>(TravelGUI.java:22)
at TravelGUI.main(TravelGUI.java:39)
```

The error is pointing at the drawString line.
I am currently using JRE 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can occur because of Java 8 unsupported version of Eclipse. Which version of Eclipse are you using. Here's the Java 8 compatibility details for eclipse
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-java8.php

If JVM cannot recognize appropriate Java version many weird behaviour may occur. So-

1. Make sure you are using a compatible version of eclipse
2. Make sure you have set JDK path correctly in your project (you may want to check that again)
3. Clean and rebuild project

This should work.

Comment: I was using one of the older helios versions of eclipse, downloaded a newer one and now it works great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It means: "A class that you use needs an other class that is not on the classpath." 
Add the required jar(s) to the classpath.